# What is the appropriate og:video:type for an external (youtube) video?

Tags: youtube, facebook-like

When facebook "Like":ing, I want to attach a youtube video in the metadata. What should I set the opengraph type to?

I couldn't find a useful answer on http://ogp.me, so I went here. The closest I get, is [how-to-post-an-youtube-video-link-through-facebook-graph-api](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3774392/how-to-post-an-youtube-video-link-through-facebook-graph-api), which is very relevant, but more general, and never mentions the type.

Perhaps it is ok to not have a type when using youtube videos?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of what YouTube uses from its own site for it's og metadata.  You can't go far wrong using their pattern.

```
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4MnpzG5Sqc">
  <meta property="og:title" content="KONY 2012">
  <meta property="og:description" content="KONY 2012 is a film and campaign by Invisible Children that aims to make Joseph Kony famous, not to celebrate him, but to raise support for his arrest and se...">
  <meta property="og:type" content="video">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/Y4MnpzG5Sqc/hqdefault.jpg">
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/Y4MnpzG5Sqc?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="224">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
```

Comment: I want to do something similar which is link to a webpage in Facebook but also attach a video, however this doesn't seem to work

Comment: remember that `og:video:url` [is mandatory](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/): *The URL of a video resource associated with the object*